# Using tensorflow in VMWare virtual machine works on one machine, not on other machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I have a VM that I've been running in VMWare Fusion on my MacBook. I use it to run a Python program that makes use of tensorflow. Everything works fine on my MacBook.

I copied the same VM to a ThinkPad. Using VMWare Workstation, I'm able to power on the machine, and run other programs within the VM just fine, but when I run the program that uses tensorflow, I get the error: `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong? I'd assume a VM should work on any machine it's run on, so I'm not sure what could be causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow and tensorflow_text. Apparently tensorflow relies on the CPU instructions that are available *at the time of its build*. Because these instructions are passed from the VM to the host machine, it can break when running the VM on a different machine.